# Is it possible to get Space Cadet 3D pinball on Vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, microsoft-pinball

Is it possible to install 3D Pinball - Space Cadet pinball on Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here are the instructions](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-7-3d-pinball-space-cadet-game/) to install the game and everything.

[This links directly to the game itself](http://mspinball.weebly.com/uploads/4/3/7/3/4373639/3d_pinball_for_windows_-_space_cadet.exe) that is inside the above link, most probably you can handle installing it and figuring out how to open the game yourself without having a step by step with pictures.